# Laravel file permission incompatibility between user running the jobs and the webserver (apache) user

Tags: laravel, file-permissions, supervisord

I have a laravel app on a VPS with apache2 and supervisord configured. The file permissions setup is the following:

- the whole project directory is owned by the `www-data` group
- Apache uses the `www-data` user
- Me and supervisor use the `app` user, which belongs to the `www-data` group.

Everything worked file until I had to handle some files both inside a job and inside a request handled by the web server. This is a summary of the flow:

- An user uploads a file. I save the file on a temp directory in the `local` disk.

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('new-directory/filename', $fileContent);
```

- I dispatch a job that should elaborate the file
- The job should delete the file at the end of the elaboration:

```
Storage::disk('local')->delete('new-directory/filename');
```

But actually what I got is a permission error, because the file is owned by the `www-user` and the `app` user that is used by supervisor to work the queue does not have the permissions to delete the file.

I tried using the 'public' visibility: `->put('new-directory/filename', $fileContent, 'public')` but the files are still protected. Here is the outpot of `ll` in the directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 60780 Dec  5 14:15 $filename
```

Is there a way to solve this file permission issue between the user that runs the queue and the webserver user?

Comment: stupid idea, but can't u add supervisor user to www-data group?

Comment: supervisor uses the `app` user, that already is in the `www-data` group

Comment: There is a way in supervisor to do this! did you try it?  adding this to the sv conf
 
`chmod=0760` then in new line
`chown=app:www-data`

Answer (score 3):

You can add in the config file in supervisor.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

Comment: Basically, I should use the www-data user for supervisor aswell

Comment: Yes. In order for the apache can delete the file uploaded from jobs. Did you get it? Please accept the answer if you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

When running queues manually, you might still need to run as `www-data` user.

```
sudo -su www-data php artisan queue:work
```

That’s if your log files are owned `www-data` which is usually the case.